# DD-WRT: Cannot connect to other clients

Tags: wireless-router, routing, dd-wrt, bridging

Kinda strange. Even though the Current Bridging Table looks as follows:

- Bridge Name: br0
- STP enabled: no
- interface: eth1 ath0 ath1

I cannot connect to clients if they belong to different interfaces. The interfaces seems to be isolated.

For example I have a NAS wired at an ethernet port (eth1). I can only access it if I connect my laptop at another ethernet port. Same between ath0 (2.4 GHz) and ath1 (5 GHz). The network configuration for both wireless interfaces is set at bridged mode under advanced settings.

My router is a TP-Link Archer C7 V2 (AC1750) and the dd-wrt firmware is v3.0-r28072 std (11/02/15)

Any suggestions regarding this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not normal behavior of DD-WRT

***Recommendation***

1. Reset to default
2. Without making any changes see if you can make both interface communication

Comment: After a reset all works as expected.

Comment: I finally pinpoint the problem. The following rule in the firewall script is causing the problem: iptables -I FORWARD ! -o tun1 -j DROP . I'm using a VPN connection and I want to prevent any access if the tunnel is not up. It works but it is causing the problem between the clients. How can I correct this rule in order to keep the above functionality and have access between clients too?

Comment: Start a new question with this as the issue it might help to have more exposure on networking site